# Is it possible to get a higher dimensional tensor as a result of `map_fn()`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to look through the tensor elements and replace them by 1d tensor like in this toy example:

```
m = tf.range(0, my_range)
res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: [t], elems=m)
```

But I am getting an exception:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError The two structures don't have the
> same nested structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List should be replaced by tensor within lambda body:

```
m = tf.range(0, my_range)
res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tf.convert_to_tensor([t]), elems=m)
```